# Parsing a CSV row into columns with the first entry in each row as the first entry in each column

Tags: python, bash, csv

I have a csv file that I need to change so that I can create an input file.  The data is set up so that it's keyname, and then data such as:

```
allendata,test@test.com,test1@test.com  
allendata2,test1@test.com,test@test.com,test3@test.com
```

I need the output formatted so that I end up with

```
allendata,test@test.com
allendata,test1@test.com
allendata2,test1@test.com
allendata2,test@test.com
allendata3,test3@test.com
```

There are about 1800 lines like this, so I'll end up with somewhere around 30000 lines when it's all parsed out.

I'll take any method possible, with bash or python being preferable.

Thanks,
Allen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using `awk` like this:

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1","$i}' file > new_file
$ cat new_file
allendata,test@test.com
allendata,test1@test.com  
allendata2,test1@test.com
allendata2,test@test.com
allendata2,test3@test.com
```

Comment: Thanks, this is easiest and quickest for my mediocre skills.  Once i get my job complete, then I can learn what i'm missing in Python.  cheers and thanks everyone for the help

Comment: You're welcome, glad it works for you.  Both `awk` and `python` are good options to manipulate text files, but I often prefer `awk` for these tasks because much of the time you can write more succinct code. i.e. lines are already split with line numbers into fields with user defined or default separators.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
fIn = open('testIn.txt', 'r')
fOut = open('testOut.txt','w')

for line in fIn:
    data = line.split(',')
    name = data[0]
    for address in data[1:]:
        fOut.write(name + ',' + address + '\n')

fIn.close()
fOut.close()
```

'textIn.txt'

```
allendata,test@test.com,test1@test.com  
allendata2,test1@test.com,test@test.com,test3@test.com
```

'testOut.txt'

```
allendata,test@test.com
allendata,test1@test.com    
allendata2,test1@test.com
allendata2,test@test.com
allendata2,test3@test.com
```

Comment: I created the testIn.txt file with my sample data and created an empty file named testOut.txt, but when I try to execute the script, I get an error   [gccadmin@gccdevaf distlists]$ python foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 8, in <module>
    fOut.write(name + ',' + address + '\n')
IOError: File not open for writing

Comment: I'm running python 2.7.3 on fedora 16.  All file permissions set to 777 and i'm execurity ./python foo.py

Comment: @AllenFerdinand: the `'r'` in the `fOut = open` line should be `'w'`.

Comment: @DSM is correct, that was a typo on my part, it should be a 'w' to open the file for writing